# How to perform NumChildren() inside a scheduled task in Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to count number of children every 5 minutes.
I've been trying to write a code to run every X minutes and every time it runs, it will calculate the number of children.

I have patched together the codes from the Firebase documentation for scheduled functions and for snapshots, but I'm probably missing something.

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 
minutes').onRun((context) => {
  var ref = firebase.database().ref("location/");
  ref.once("value")
   .then(function(snapshot) {
     var a = snapshot.numChildren(); // 1 ("name")
    });
});
```

I'm getting a console error when trying to deploy to Firebase cloud:

8:3   error    Expected catch() or return   promise/catch-or-return

9:11  warning  Unexpected function expression prefer-arrow-callback

9:11  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return

Answer (score 1):

Since the `once()` call loads data from Firebase asynchronously, you need to tell Cloud Functions when your code is done. You do this by returning a promise from the top-level code, and then a value from within there.

So something like this:

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 
minutes').onRun((context) => {
  var ref = firebase.database().ref("location/");
  return ref.once("value")
   .then(function(snapshot) {
     var a = snapshot.numChildren(); // 1 ("name")
     return true;
    });
});
```

Also see:

- [firebase Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117203/firebase-function-returned-undefined-expected-promise-or-value/54117644#54117644)
- [How to fix "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value" when creating a function for Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56501586/how-to-fix-function-returned-undefined-expected-promise-or-value-when-creatin/56501833#56501833)
- [Firebase cloud functions inconsistent with bulk updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45797752/firebase-cloud-functions-inconsistent-with-bulk-updates/45798137#45798137)